# Mule 3.7 insufficient memory for JVM

Tags: docker, java-8, mule

I am trying to run mule 3.7 in [Java:8](https://hub.docker.com/_/java/) docker image. However it fails "JVM exited while loading the application."

Here is the Dockerfile

```
FROM java:8
WORKDIR /opt
ENV MULE_VERSION 3.7.0
RUN wget     https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/distributions/mule-
standalone/3.7.0/mule-standalone-3.7.0.tar.gz

RUN tar xvzf /opt/mule-standalone-3.7.0.tar.gz
RUN rm /opt/mule-standalone-3.7.0.tar.gz
RUN ln -s /opt/mule-standalone-3.7.0 /opt/mule 
EXPOSE 8081
RUN echo "Running mule"
CMD [ "/opt/mule/bin/mule" ]
```

Here is the dump of the error

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/hshira/3c1ba0d79a42a29a4e7d/raw/ee35eb650c1c9edbc3889f5e8bebdd1698643123/gistfile1.txt

Answer (score 1):

You need to have at least 1GB of Java Heap on startup.  What this is telling you is that you dont have either enough memory allocated in your -Xms----M setting or the machine doesn't have the physical memory that you need for Mule 3.7.x

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the memory size by following command

set JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m"

After setting up it requires a system restart.